# Limit time change in Windows

Tags: windows, time

Is there a way to limit the users ability to change time by more than an hour?

Comment: But what if the user changes the time one hour forward, then another hour forward, then another hour forward, then another hour forward, then... Well, you get my point... :-)

Comment: Good point. Never underestimate the lengths malicious people will go to to undermine something, or the lengths a "dumb" user will sometimes go to trying to solve a problem their way instead of asking for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no setting to control how "much" users can change the time, but Windows does have a setting in the domain security policy that can be set to disallow time changes.  By default, only Administrators and Power Users can set the time on a domain workstation.  This can be changed in the Default Domain Security Settings on the domain controller.  Navigate to the Security Settings, Local Policies, then User Rights Assignment.  There is a property called "Change the system time" which you can use to set the permissions on who can change the time on workstations, servers, and domain controllers.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so - I think you can either change the time or you can't, at least with the built in tools. If the machine is in a domain, be aware that fiddling with the time will cause people to have problems with authentication to domain resources.